# correct way to prevent SPF failures

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spam, spf

I have a website on a hosted server whose mail users are using their ISPs SMTP to send mail.

I have set their SPF record to look like this:

```
v=spf1 mx a:comcast.net ip4:216.70.103.0/24 ip4:216.70.101.0/24 ip4:76.96.53.0/24 -all
```

- the SMTP host is comcast.net, 76.96.53.0/24 is the ip range they get assigned from.
- ip4:216.70.103.0/24 ip4:216.70.101.0/24 are the two possible SMTP ranges they could get IF they used their hosting account mail servers [media temple]

They are still getting SPF errors, any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think you need to set `mx:comcast.net` instead of `a:comcast.net` because the mailservers are not listed as an A record under comcast.net.